# Ordering for a todo list with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to create my own todo list using Javascript, Python and MongoDB.  I'm getting stuck on how to handle the task ordering.

My current idea is to have an order field in each task document and when the order changes on the client I would grab the task list from the db and reorder each task individually/sequentially.  This seems awkward because large todo lists would mean large amount of queries.  Is there a way to update a field in multiple documents sequentially?

I'm also looking for advice as to whether this is the best way to do this.  I want to be able to maintain the todo list order but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a658f2cace55034c68ce95"),
  "order" : 1,
  "title" : "task1",
  "complete" : 0
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a658fecace55034c68ce96"),
  "order" : 2,
  "title" : "task2",
  "complete" : 1
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a65907cace55034c68ce97"),
  "order" : 3,
  "title" : "task3",
  "complete" : 1
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a65911cace55034c68ce98"),
  "order" : 4,
  "title" : "task4",
  "complete" : 0
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a65919cace55034c68ce99"),
  "order" : 5,
  "title" : "task5",
  "complete" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo is very very fast with queries, you should not be as concerned with performance as if you were using a full featured relational database. If you want to be prudent, just create a todo list of 1k items and try it out, it should be pretty instant.

```
for (var i = 0; i < orderedListOfIds.length; i++)
{
  db.collection.update({ '_id': orderedListOfIds[i] }, { $set: { order:i } })
}
```

then

```
db.collection.find( { } ).sort( { order: 1 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mongo allows for updating multiple documents. Just use a [modifier operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations) and `multi=True`. For example, this increments `order` by one for all documents with `order` greater than five:

```
todos.update({'order':{'$gt':5}}, {'$inc':{'order':1}}, multi=True)
```

As to the best way, usually it's better to use a "natural" ordering (by name, date, priority etc) rather than create a fake field just for that.

Comment: Assuming I grabbed only tasks `{"complete": 0}` I would have order 1, 4 and 5.  Would this then give me order 2, 5 and 6 or would it set the first document's order to 1 and the next would be 2 and the third 3?

Comment: `$inc:{x:1}` is the same as `x += 1` in python (given that x exists).

Comment: Ok so it would only increment each tasks order by 1.  I want to renumber a tasks order based on what the client did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar. I added a field `ind` to my list items. Here's how I move a list item to a new location:

```
moveItem: function (sourceIndex, targetIndex) {
    var id = Items.findOne({ind:sourceIndex})._id;
    var movinUp = targetIndex > sourceIndex;
    shift = movinUp ? -1 : 1;
    lowerIndex = Math.min(sourceIndex, targetIndex);
    lowerIndex += movinUp ? 1 : 0;
    upperIndex = Math.max(sourceIndex, targetIndex);
    upperIndex -= movinUp ? 0 : 1;
    console.log("Shifting items from "+lowerIndex+" to "+upperIndex+" by "+shift+".");
    Items.update({ind: {$gte: lowerIndex,$lte: upperIndex}}, {$inc: {ind:shift}},{multi:true});
    Items.update(id, {$set: {ind:targetIndex}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using native promises (es6) in mongoose `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` you can do the following to batch:

```
function batchUpdate(res, req, next){
  let ids = req.body.ids
  let items = []
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    items.push(db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:ids[i] }, { $set: { order:i } }))

  Promise.all(items)
    .then(() => res.status(200).send())
    .catch(next)
}
```